# Creating new block for getChildHtml() - Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, block

I'm trying to add updateinfo block onto customer page.

I put this code inside `customer.xml` layout

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="updateinfo" as="updateinfo"/>
<reference name="updateinfo">
<block type="core/template" name="updateinfoBlock" template="customer/update_info.phtml" />
</reference>
```

and added `update_info.phtml` into customer folder.

also added 
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('updateinfo') ?>` 
to customer page
but I'm still not getting anything. Stuck.

Comment: Can you post your `update_info.phtml` code?

Comment: it's just simple div with some random text inside <p> for beginning before I configure it to appear. It doesn't appear in template hint paths so I assume that it doesn't load into page

Comment: could you post your customer.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try like the below code

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="updateinfo" as="updateinfo">  
   <block type="core/template" name="updateinfoBlock" template="customer/update_info.phtml" /> 
</block>
```

to get to this block you can get like this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('updateinfo') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
getChildHtml('updateinfoBlock') ?>
```

instead of:

`getChildHtml('updateinfo') ?>`

Comment: still nothing, even tried to put it inside page.xml but also nothing. P.S. I'm Flushing Magento cache everytime

Comment: Whole code should be like: `<?php echo getChildHtml('updateinfoBlock') ?>` You can also try to put your xml into `page.xml` or `local.xml` to be certain.

Comment: i know that it should look like that, that's what i called

Comment: I managed to get through it without making a new block inside xml with <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('customer/update_info.phtml')->toHtml();?>

Comment: Danijel,creating an inline block definitely works,  however preferably changes made to a local.xml and using block updates and handles are easier to find and prevents issues later on down the road.  Your format of your layout update wouldn't work unless you have a custom module that uses the reference name of "updateinfo"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `getChildHtml()`, you want to set `as` attribute of your block along with `name` attribute. Name attribute is normally using to refer in the layout file itself.If you need to call a block through a template file, the value specified in `as` attribute is used.  So you need your block definition something like this

```
<block type="core/template" name="updateinfoBlock" as="update.info.block" template="customer/update_info.phtml" />
```

and you need to call this block as

```
 <?php $this->getChildHtml('update.info.block'); ?>
```

However the parent block of your `core/template` block is of type `core/text_list`. Children inside that type of block will render automatically. Mean you don't need to call those children by `getChildHtml()` method. Some examples are `left`, `right`, `content` blocks. Blocks inside them will render automatically.

So put your block of type `core/template` anywhere you need in your layout directly and call it as I shown above. You don't need to enclose it in another block as you did, unless it is essential.